# Variable set to empty from JSON, not returning null

Tags: php, json

I'm calling in data from a JSON file. One of my elements is:

```
"mainImg_select":""
```

Sometimes this has a value, sometimes it won't - in this case it's empty. I put this (as well as other) variables in an object called Product.

When trying to set `$product -> mainImg`, I'm trying to see whether the JSON value is empty or not. If it's empty, I want to get the first value of another set of images, `$more_imgs`and make that the main image. Here's my code:

```
if(!is_null($mainImg)) {
    $product->mainImage = $html->find($mainImg, 0)->src;
    for ($idx = 0; $idx < 10; $idx++) {
        $more = $html->find($more_imgs, $idx);
        if (!is_null($more)) {
            $product->moreImages[$idx] = $more->src;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
} else {
    for ($idx = 0; $idx < 10; $idx++) {
        $more = $html->find($more_imgs, $idx);
        if (($idx == 0) && (!is_null($more))) {
            $product->mainImage = $more->src;
        } elseif (!is_null($more)) {
            $product->moreImages[$idx] = $more->src;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` in relation to `$product->mainImage = $html->find($mainImg, 0)->src;`

I assume this has something to do with the `if(!is_null($mainImg))` above it, because $mainImg SHOULD be null as defined in the JSON. If not, what's the best thing to use here?

EDIT: Here's some more detailed code for when the Product object is being set:
http://pastebin.com/EEUgpwgn

Comment: what is the type of the variable `$html`? Prefer the `if(!empty($mainImg))` condition to test if your value is either null or empty.

Comment: HTML is set by `$html = str_get_html(curl($infoLink));` where `$infoLink`is a URL.

Comment: non-object means that either `$product` or `$html` isn't an object.

Comment: Ok you have to precise you use the _PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser_ Library. And you have to check if the HTML element linked by `$mainImg` exists on your HTML, otherwise it will have a notice when you will access the `src` from a `null` object.

Comment: I am indeed using PHP Simple HTML Dom. @RMcLeod, that's bizarre because a few lines above this code I successfully parse both $product and $html. I'll edit in more complete code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `!is_null` to `!empty` as `is_null()` will return false even if "mainImg_select" is equal to empty string "".

Answer (score 1):

Whether the `$mainImg` isn't found on your HTML; the code `$html->find($mainImg, 0)` will return `null` and then you will attempt to access the `src` parameter of a `null` object.

( from the [Documentation of the php simple HTML Parser Library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) :

```
// Find (N)th anchor, returns element object or null if not found (zero based)
$ret = $html->find('a', 0);
```

)

You have to do this:

```
if (null !== ($img = $html->find($mainImg, 0))) {
   $imgSrc = $img->src; // Here the HTML Element exists and you can access to the src parameter
}
```